# returning abstract C++ struct to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, export, abstract

I have a C++ DLL which returns a pointer to a struct which is abstract, this hides the interface of the underlying class. The DLL exports just one function, getInstance, which creates an object of a C++ struct which inherits from this abstract struct, and returns it as a pointer to the abstract struct type.

As far as I can find C# does not allow abstract structs, and you can't have a pointer to a C# class, so I can't think of a way of getting this struct from C++ to C#

Thanks.

Comment: A C++ struct is just like a C++ class, there's no real difference (at least where C++/C# interop is concerned...). What do you want to do with the struct? Call its methods?

Comment: Yes I do want to call its methods, GetInstance just returns a pointer to that struct type, so I need to declare a struct with the same definition as the C++ abstract struct that is returned by GetInstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, structs and classes are the same. The only difference is that they default to different access specifies (struct uses public by default, class defaults to private).

So your abstract C++ struct becomes a C# *class*, not *struct*.

Comment: Well, C# doesn't normally have pointers at all, unless you delve into unsafe code. But I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Why do you (think you) need a pointer in C# at all?

Comment: because that's what the C++ DLL returns, I can't return an instance of an abstract class or struct in C++, it has to be a pointer.

Comment: They have nothing to do with each others. Your C++ function returns a C++ pointer to a C++ class. The interop code will have to translate that into something that C# understands, such as a C# reference to a C# class. But you haven't shown us any actual code, so we have no way of giving you a precise answer

Comment: So the interop will turn the pointer into a reference? I didn't know that, so if I have a function that returns a pointer to a struct in C++ then can I just assign a C# struct object to the return value of that function like:

    StructObj someObj = FuncReturningStructPtr();

as long as the structs are packed the same way in memory?

Comment: We don't know what it will do, because it's your code, not ours, and you haven't shown us a single line of it. I'm just saying that conceptually, a C# reference is pretty much the equivalent of a C++ pointer. But if you want to ask us and get *useful* answers, we'll need to know what your code actually *does*